# Protractor repeat specs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, bdd

I have a case like this

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: [
        'test/scenarios/user/login.js',
        'test/scenarios/user/choose_user_1.js',
        'test/scenarios/user/change_user.js',
        'test/scenarios/user/choose_user_2.js',
        'test/scenarios/user/change_user.js',
        'test/scenarios/user/choose_user_3.js',
        'test/scenarios/user/logout.js'
    ]
}
```

But protractor doesn't reuse change_user.js more than once..
I have to create change_user_1.js and change_user_2.js to get what I want.. Is there a way to deactivate this behavior, or I should do my tests differently?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you cannot call same script twice. We had similar issue and here's what I did to fix it - Use [`jasmine-data-provider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider), create separate suites instead of scripts and loop through them using data provider. Here are the steps that i would follow -

1. Install `jasmine-data-provider` npm package.
2. Create two `describe` suites, one for `choose_user` and the other for `change_user`.
3. Pass multiple data to these describe suites using `jasmine-data-provider`.
4. Each time a `choose_user` - `describe` runs, a `change_user` - `describe` also runs next to that.

Here's a sample code -

```
var dp = require('../node_modules/jasmine-data-provider'); //Install the npm package and provide its path

//Data provider object to store data that script uses
var objectDataProvider = {
    'Test1': {user1: 'user_1'},
    'Test2': {user1: 'user_2'},
    'Test3': {user1: 'user_3'},
};

//Jasmine Data Provider function automatically loops through the tests - Test1, Test2, Test3
dp(objectDataProvider, function (data) {

    describe('choose_user Test:', function(){
        //Choose User specs that's applicable for one user
        //To use the objectDataProvider data use - data.user1 all the time
    });

    describe('change_user Test:', function(){
        //Change User specs that's applicable for one user
    });

});
```

This script should run `choose_user` and `change_user` specs 3 times and then you can continue execution with rest of the scripts in pipe.

Hope it helps.